# Track Time spent by an user,Successful Registration by Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

Actually I want to track the time an user spent in App , successful login event and registration event  in my App using Google Analytics. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Get it the start time and store it somewhere  when the app starts the Registration activity.

```
long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Also get the end time after the user logged in to the app.

```
long endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Get the time spent by the user.

```
long timeSpent = endTime - startTime;
```

Then use the 'GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().setCustomVar()' method to set this data inside your track event.